# What happens when there is no value assigned in a switch statement in java?

Tags: java, switch-statement, trace

I'm working on a switch statement and I'm wondering what happens when an argument is called with no value assigned?

For example if I called argument A, what would the execution look like?

```
switch (letter) {
    case 'A':
    case 'b': value = 2; break;
    default: value = 1;
}
```

System.out.println(letter + "is worth" + value + "lollies"
}

Answer (score 1):

If letter = 'A' then case 'A' will be executed until the next break is encountered.
As case 'A' is a no-op then case'b' will be executed value = 2 then the break would prevent the default case being executed.